# Show Toast Message if RecyclerView is empty

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progressdialog, toast

I am setting `RecyclerView` in my Fragment.When there is no items in RecyclerView I want to show message `No data`.But I am confused where to put this inside RecyclerView.If there are no items in RecyclerView `progressbar` keeps Loading.I want to dismiss progressbar when there is no items in recyclerview.
This is code for setting RecyclerView

```
private void getData() {
        String restqueue_req = "restqueue_req";
        String url = "";
            progressDialog.show();
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            final CurrentEntry entry = new CurrentEntry();
                            String id = object.getString("id");
                            url = "";
                            JsonObjectRequest foodie_request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    try {
                                        String first_name = response.getString("firstname");
                                        String last_name = response.getString("lastname");
                                        entry.setName(first_name + "\t" + last_name);
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                }
                            }) {
                                @Override
                                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                                    String auth = "JWT " + myToken;
                                    headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                    return headers;
                                }
                            };
                            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(foodie_request, foodie_data_req);
                            String no_of_people = object.getString("people");
                            String t = object.getString("t");
                            entry.setPeople(people);
                            entry.setEstimate(t);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            current.add(entry);
                            adapter = new CurrentAdapter(current, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Where to handle this condition for Empty RecyclerView ?

Comment: in your adapter class

Comment: RecyclerView doesn't have an emptyView support, we gotta fix that. `https://gist.github.com/adelnizamutdinov/31c8f054d1af4588dc5c`

Answer (score 3):

You can check `isEmpty()` for `Array List` you are using.

[**`isEmpty()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty()) Returns `true` if list contains no elements.

Like

```
current.add(entry);
if(current.isEmpty()){
  Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"No data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
  adapter = new CurrentAdapter(current, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: @Satya You can correct the answer mark as accepted like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png and upvote if it solved your problem so it is useful for future visitors

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, If you Check [**`length()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#length()).

> Returns the number of values in this array.

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) 
 {
                    try {
                        if(response.length()== 0)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Empty List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                         ...
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way would be to registerAdapterDataObserver as follows:

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                if(adapter.getItemCount()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No data available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //You can show toast or choose any other option
                }
            }
        });
```

This will make your code for Adapter clean and allow you to freely modify the presentation without modifying Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

check in your adapter class if size of response list is 0 then show a toast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  current.add(entry);

  if(current.size()>0){
  adapter = new CurrentAdapter(current, 
                        getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }else{
   Toast.makeText(context, "RecycleView Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

**xml layout**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/empty_tv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:visibility="gone"
android:text="no_data" />
```

**java class**

```
 recycler_view = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
 empty_tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_tv);

if (no_data.isEmpty()) {
recycler_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
empty_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
else {
recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
empty_tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

try this code it helps you

Answer (score 0):

here is a way after editing the answers and try many ways

try this

**in fragment/activity class**

```
recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_recent);
    emptytext = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.emptytext);
    adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();


            if (adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                emptytext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                emptytext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


        }
    });
```

**in layout xml**

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_recent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptytext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="the activiy has no data" />
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers helped to effectively handle my case. I have a home fragment with RecyclerView to display list of devices user has added. My requirement is to display background image with some instructions if there is no device.

The device list is stored as an observable map. The map resides in a singleton object. My RecyclerView.Adapter class directly refers to this observable map and populates it to the UI.

This is how I am returning the item count,

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int size = DeviceDatabase.getList().size(); // gives size of the map
    return size;
}
```

I implemented registerAdapterDataObserver in my fragment class to show and hide the background image but it is not getting called if there are no devices in the map.

I solved my problem by adding an interface in my adapter class to notify fragment class if the device list is empty or not and I called it from getItemCount function as below.

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private DevListAdapterListener mListener;
    DeviceListAdapter(DevListAdapterListener devListAdapterListener) {
        mListener = devListAdapterListener;
    }

    public interface DevListAdapterListener {
        void onListEmpty(boolean isEmpty);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int size = DeviceDatabase.getList().size(); // gives size of the map
        if (size <= 0) {
            mListener.onListEmpty(true);
        } else {
            mListener.onListEmpty(false);
        }
        return size;
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

The handling in the home fragment is,

```
@Override
public void onListEmpty(boolean isEmpty) {
    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View view = requireView().findViewById(R.id.device_list_background); // Background image in home fragment XML
            if (isEmpty) {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I wanted to show/hide the background image only when the list gets populated on the UI, calling an interface from getItemCount helped me do that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

In your recyclerview adapter class there is a method name

adaperclass constructor

```
 AdapterClass(ArrayList<String>array){
if(array.size==0){
  Toast.makeText(context,"Array is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
  }
```

Comment: onBindViewHolder won't be called if the list is empty